# div table-cell and overflow not working

Tags: css

Why is this overflow not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/kacx4kad/

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_cell">
            wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.table_row {
    display:table-row;
}

.table_cell {
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;

    background:red;
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the structure of your code you need **display property value** of **inline-block** for **.table_cell** for the **overflow** value to take effect. Otherwise, you'd have change things around.

```css
.table {
 display:table;
 width:100%;
}

.table_row {
 display:table-row;
}

.table_cell {
 position:relative;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
    
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_cell">
            wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee<br>wee
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```